# CSS Layout - Scrolling doesn't work in side the columns

Tags: html, css

I'm working to build a CSS layout that has a fixed header, lefCol and Right Col, but the height of the MainCenterColumn (#mainCol) can scroll.

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/DscT6/

The issue with this is, on the mac you can scroll by dragging your fingers on the touchpad. I noticed that the scrolling only works if you mouse is over the MailCol, if your mouse is over the Left or Right Col the page doesn't scroll. Any ideas? Have you seen this? Suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Hmm… somehow exactly what I would expect to happen? The `#viewer` is the one that scrolls (via `overflow:auto`), why should it scroll anywhere else? Imagine you'd have two scrollable elements on the page — you'd have a problem if it would behave anyhow differently, or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: Are you using a Mac? if you have your mouse over the right or left columns and try to scroll with TOUCH/noMouse.... The the page doesn't scroll, which is a real bad UX.

Comment: Ahh jezz just figured it out, adding a z index, to the viewer did the trick. Still interested if anyone smarter than recommend a cleaner solution :)

Comment: Yep, I am using a Mac and I understand why this bothers you. Yet, I'm still under the impression that this done by design and for a pretty good reason: Imagine you would have two scrollable columns next to each other. Which one would scroll if your mouse would be outside the both of them? I think your layout and the position of the scrollbar should clearly indicate which part can be scrolled and the user will act accordingly. I've been using the multitouch pad on the Mac for as long as it has been existing and I can't remember a case where scrolling would have behaved oddly on a website.

Comment: Could you show your solution? Now I'm wondering if I've misunderstood you…

Answer (score 1):

Here http://jsfiddle.net/laukstein/DscT6/3/ it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with polarblau, if you add `overflow: auto` that element will automatically have the scroll as needed, if you remove the `overflow` rule the entire page will have the height of the highest element and so it will scroll.